# Acceleo UI doesn't generate any files

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

I have a GMF editor and an Acceleo UI project that I would like to bundle in a single plugin. That's not the matter though.

You see, when executed in the runtime (Run as > Eclipse Application), both the GMF editor and the Acceleo UI project work fine and dandy.

However, when exported as plugins and installed into Eclipse, only the GMF editor will work. The Acceleo UI item WILL show up in the context menu, and it will create the target folder for the files. But this folder will be empty.

Is there a reason why one plugin would work properly while the other does not? Is there any additional configuring that must be done in the Acceleo UI for it to work outside the runtime?

Searching the Eclipse Forums, I found something about adding a line 'outputFolder="${target.folder}"' to a file "acceleo.build", but I can't find neither the file nor the line anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm working on Eclipse Mars with version 3.6.3.201602090916 of Acceleo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I know nobody ever replied to me, but I found out the problem so I might as well post it in case someone runs into the same issue in the future.

The issue was that Acceleo needs a file with extension .*emtl* to work. This file wasn't showing up anywhere when exporting the plugin, though. I thought it was failing to compile it (as the .*etml* is actually a compiled form of the .*mtl* file).

After some digging, I found out Acceleo does actually create said file, but it doesn't put it in the same place where the .*mtl* is - it actually places it in a folder called "bin", which isn't created by default when exporting the plugin. In order to see this "bin" folder, I had to mark it in "Build Configuration", in the *build.properties* file.

Then, I manually copied the .*etml* in "bin" to the plugin's "main" folder (where the .*mtl* file resides) and that was it, it worked like a charm.